# Remove Default Selection from a DataBound ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have data bind a combo box with a list of values in the database, now, the first record is being displayed as a default value, i need to change this and set to blank or my custom message, any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` directly to get a custom message, such as:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox1.Text = "Select an item";
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty item as the first item to the DataSource before binding is the ugly fix for this issue.

Setting the SelectedIndex as -1 might help.

Below is another option, but you may have to validate when retrieving the selected item.

```
comboBox.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Just create an empty object of the relevant type and Insert/Add to the list/collection that you want to data bind.

Answer (score -1):

After binding data to your combobox, insert new item at index 0:

```
combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Default Value");
```

or

```
combobox1.Items.Insert(0, ""); //Empty
```

Comment: Argument Exception: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.